# Chrome extension help - what's the process for adding the url of an open page to the html of the default_popup in manifest.json

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, google-chrome-extension

I've got the following manifest:

```
{
    "name":"Fix the Web extension",
    "version":"0.2",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "description":"Web accessibility Poorly designed websites can exclude some disabled people. If disabled people report problems and volunteers push for improvements, Fix the Web crowdsources change.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "FTW-favicon-128.png",
        "default_title": "Fix the Web | Disabled people: Report an issue now!",
        "default_popup": "extension.html"
        },
    "icons":{
        "128": "FTW-favicon-128.png"
    }
}
```

which opens this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Disabled people: Report an issue now! | Fix the Web</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.fixtheweb.net/frame/report" height="350" width="300"></iframe>
</body>
</HTML>
```

but what I want is to add ?url=http://www.mysite.com/something in the iframe link so it becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Disabled people: Report an issue now! | Fix the Web</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.fixtheweb.net/frame/report?url=http://www.mysite.com/something" height="350" width="300"></iframe>
</body>
</HTML>
```

I've seen other related posts but I'm feeling a bit stupid - I think it has something to do with ajax or javascript.... help much appreciated, and it's for a good cause (fixtheweb.net is a web accessibility charity) so comes with bonus karma points :)

Comment: Have `extension.html` load `extension.js`, and use the [activeTab](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission.

Comment: I can kind of see where you're going... any chance you could elaborate on what goes into extension.js ? and how that sets the url in extension.html? That activeTab page you linked to didn't give me enough info (I am fairly dim when it comes to javascript it has to be said...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extension.js`

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabArray){
    document.getElementById("eltId").src
        = "http://www.fixtheweb.net/frame/report?url="+tabArray[0].url;
});
```

and add `"permissions": ["activeTab"]` to your manifest.  Then, to load it from extension.html, you'll need:

```
<body>
 <iframe id="eltId" src="http://www.fixtheweb.net/frame/report" height="350" width="300"></iframe>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extension.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm honestly surprised it didn't end up taking more.

Comment: By the way, the popup will load a lot faster if you skip the iframe and just have the source page as part of the extension.

Comment: Fantastic. Do you want a credit somewhere on the site?

Comment: As for putting the source page as part of the extension I don't think it'd work because it's a form generated by drupal which pre fills your email address if you're logged in on the site. It is a shame it's slow though. I did try just saving that page into the extension when I was first setting this up but the form wouldn't submit (i just saved the source code as an html file). Any ideas?

Comment: Does this mean the extension will be expecting you to be logged in so that it can submit an accessibility issue?  Why not just be content with people not filling in their email address?  When you tried saving the html file locally, did you change the form to be submitted to the full url, and not a relative url?

Answer (score 0):

wooo, nearly nearly...
I replaced extension.html with the source page, and made all the urls to the full urls... and now it works and is faster but the extension.js is no longer pre filling the url of the open page.

what I tried was changing the js so that it reads as below because "report-form" is the id of the form (the source of which can be found at http://www.fixtheweb.net/frame/report of course)

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabArray){
    document.getElementById("report-form").src
        = "http://www.fixtheweb.net/frame/report?url="+tabArray[0].url;
});
```

we need people (reporters) to fill in their email address because that's how volunteers can get back to reporters if they have queries, or want to tell them about fixes, or if reporters want to catch up on where the issue is getting to...
I'm hoping the extension will work whether you are logged in or not. Sadly this way even when you are logged in the email address no longer pre fills... but if I had to compromise on that for a faster form load I think that's worth it as reporters won't always be logged in.