# How to get current tab url while opening the popup [without tabs permission]

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a browserAction extension testing on chrome 31.0.1650.57. I want to get active tab url when the user click on the extension icon, save it and use it later.

I am able to do that when using **tabs** permission. But this permission has a lot of power (that I don't need) and users are complaining about this.

I followed the article to switch to **activeTab** permission http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab but it only works when there is no popup. As you can see in the **[make_page_red](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red.zip)** example.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log("★ tab.url", tab.url);
});
```

You can check by changing the **[make_page_red](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red.zip)** example manifest file to add a default popup like this:

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"  ←-------------------

  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Now because I have a default popup the browserAction.onClicked listener is not called anymore.

*How can I get current tab url and still have my popup opening?*

Thanks

Comment: Could you show what you have already (manifest and popup.html)?  I've gotten activeTab to work with a browser action at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22057017/2336725

Comment: @Teepeemm I tried with your answer but the tab object has no url property

Comment: I believe that popup.html means that browserAction.onClicked is not called.  Perhaps have popup.hmlt just get the tab url directly?  And could you post more of what you have already?

Comment: @Teepeemm I am using the make_page_red sample. See my updated description. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

browserAction.onClicked is not called anymore (as you noted), so just skip that:

`popup.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabArray){
    console.log(tabArray[0].url);
});
```

And of course, have `popup.html` load `popup.js` with a `script` tag.  (And I'm not sure what you're background script is doing.)

Edit:

In addition to the above,  my extension has two other files.  `manifest.json` is copied from yours,  but has the background section deleted.  The only other file is `popup.html` (from memory, so bear with me):

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script></body></html>
```

To view the console,  I click the browser action,  which brings up a 50 pixel square window.  Right click on that, "inspect element", and click console to view the url.

Comment: I am using the make_page_red example. Your code doesn't work. It returns undefined. Why are you still unsure about the background.js? It did ridiculously nothing.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I asked about the background script because when I copied your manifest, chrome complained that it couldn't find the script.  I've gotten this to work.  If you can't,  then (for the third time) could you post what you have (everything)?

Comment: What version of chrome are you running?

Comment: Version 33.0.1750.149.  Now for the fourth time, will you post all of what you have done?  Or will you keep saying "it doesn't work", and expect me to psychically divine what you're doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know why it is working today. I didn't change anything… so I suspect Chrome runtime was in buggy state. The full computer restart fixed things. Thanks for your help