# Display the url of current web page into a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try to display the URL of the current web page in a chrome extension. I just begin javascript and chrome extension dev.

My manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "0.1",
"name": "!!!",
"author": "!!!",
"description": "Extension !!!",
"icons": {
    "default_icon": "logo2.png"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo2.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"options_page": "options.html",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"]
}],
"web_accessible_resources": ["contentscript.js"],
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

My popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Extension !!!!!!!!!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="tracker.js"> </script>
<script src="canvas.js"></script>-->
<script src="background.js"></script>
<script src="contentscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!--=========TITLE============== -->
    <div id="main-logo">        
        <div id="logo"><img src="logo2.png"><img></div>
        <h1>!!!!</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <!--=============Display URL===========-->
        <div id="main-url">
            <script src="background.js"></script>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

My contentscript.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({
url: window.location.href
}, function(response) {
console.log(response.farewell);
);
```

My background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
        "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
        "from the extension !!TEST!!");
}
);
```

Nothing diplay in my popup and in the console...

Thanks for your help
Best regards

Comment: You're loading your scripts twice: once as a content script or background script and once in popup.html.  Which do you want?  What should trigger the request and subsequent message in popup / console?

Comment: And this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/22389039/2336725

Answer (score 1):

chrome.extension.sendRequest is deprecated. You should use chrome.runtime.sendMessage:

**Sender**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  url: window.location.href
}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
);
```

**Receiver**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.url==="http://xxxxx.com"){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({farewell:"bingo"},function(response){});
    }
  }
);
```

BTW, as @Teepeemm said, you don't have to load content script and background js twice. contentscript.js will be injected into web context according to the matches pattern. And background.js will be executed once the extension start running

Comment: your suggestion is correct, but you still use sendRequest() in your code. Please, edit your code.