# Display informations storaged in localStorage in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm developping a chrome extension which have to display time spent on visited websites. I use `localStorage` for storage persistent informations (url and time spent).

For the time, I can't display url in my div "main-stat" (and not in console). Do you have an idea ? 
I surely forgot things and made mistakes...
Here are my differents files.

My manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "options_page": "/option/options.html",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["contentscript.js"],
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

My popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="clear.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <!--=============STATS ===========-->
    <div id="main-stats">

    </div>
    <!--=============Restart timer===========-->
    <div id="main-bouton">
            <div id="bouton1">
        <a href="popup.html" id ="bouton">Restart timer</a>

        </div>
    </div>                          
</body>
</html>
```

My contentscript.js

```
var lastPing = +new Date();

function ping() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        domain: location.host,
        lastPing: lastPing
    }, function() {
        lastPing = +new Date();
        console.log('Ping send');
    });
}

setInterval(ping, 5000);
```

My background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var domain = request.domain;
    var lastPing = request.lastPing;
    var time_elapsed = localStorage.getItem(domain) || 0;
    localStorage.setItem(domain, time_elapsed + (+new Date() - lastPing));
});
```

My popup.js

```
for (var key in localStorage) {
  console.log(key, localStorage.getItem(key));
}
```

My clear.js

```
document.getElementById("bouton").addEventListener("click", function clear(){
  localStorage.clear();
  console.log("Stats have been restarted !");
}, false);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for results in the right console? Are you using "Inspect popup"?

Comment: Yes I use this console..I have the following mistake: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ping " contentscript.js l4

Comment: Why are you loading `contentscript.js` and `background.js` in your popup?

Comment: You moved your clear.js to the head, but by the time it's executed DOM is not yet ready, and `document.getElementById` will fail. You need to either use something like jQuery's `$(document).ready` or move that particular script to the end of the document.

Comment: Do you still have trouble, or is your question answered?

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works ! Url and time elapsed are displayed in console :) now i will try to display these two in my popup interface maybe with .innerHTML .

Comment: Save yourself some pain and switch to using jQuery, there is no reason not to.

Comment: Yes the twice way are good (jquery or script at the end).  I have an other problem: I would like to have the date in format hours:minutes:secondes but I have a date like this 6546165151210002223300223155220021350021351320021515 ??!!

Comment: Sorry, but: stop. Questions on SO are meant to ask about one particular problem. If you have further questions: mark this question as answered and make a new one. That's why I objected to your edits with the latest code. Make sure to read the [introduction to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: So URLs and time elapsed are well diplay in console. Now I don't know how can I diplay these in my div main-stats (it's my question of departure)? Can you help me please.

Comment: Same argument: make a question per problem; also, try to research the question. Look at some jQuery tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The above code seems to be fine, except that you can't use JavaScript in an HTML page due to 
Chrome's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution). According to it, inline JavaScript will **not** be executed.

Comment: Thx but I tested with a extern javascript file without result.

Comment: Then there might be some problem in message passing...can u plz paste ur latest code?

Comment: I edited my code without inline js. I call my scripts (popup.js and clear.js) in my divs ..Is it a good way?

Comment: @user3529586 It's better to do so either in the head, or near the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Two</s> Three points:

1. You're using `chrome.runtime.sendRequest`, which is undefined. Apparently you implemented the non-edited version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051124/934239). The proper function would be `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.
2. For whatever reason, you're also loading your `contentscript.js` and `background.js` into the popup. They do not belong there.
3. You should be mindful of where you put your scripts. Typically, scripts are put in the `<head>` tag (especially since you don't have page load speed issues in extensions), but if your code assumes that the DOM is already built, you either need to wrap it in something like jQuery's `$(document).ready` or put it at the end of your `<body>` tag.

Comment: Note to the OP: it's very hard to maintain answers if you just repeatedly edit the question with your latest version (bringing more errors)